# Vuetify : On <Autocomple> component How bring my own custom `v-list-item`

Tags: vuetify.js

In Vuetify components-lib there is a hint that on  I can bring my own custom `v-list-item` with `slot:item`

```json
// item
// Description
// Define a custom item appearance

// Props
{
  parent: VueComponent
  item: object
  on: object // Only needed when providing your own v-list-item
  attrs: object // Only needed when providing your own v-list-item
}
```

How can I achive that? because when I do

```html
<template v-slot:item="data">
   <book :book="data.item"></book>
</template>
```

Vutifiey warp-up it with own `v-list-item` and I want to put some custom class on part ot the `v-list-item`s

Answer (score 1):

It is a very common scenario to add some custom styling in the `v-auto-complete`'s list. But, there is no way of avoiding `v-list/v-list-item` as Vuetify does not give you the full control of the dropdown menu.

As you may have noticed that dropdown menu is like the `v-menu` and the input element for `v-autocomplete` is the activator of the dropdown menu. So, this is how the `v-autocomplete` component works:

- Vuetify creates a dropdown menu and add its own logic(HTML, CSS, JS) into it.
- it gives users the slots to add custom markup/components inside the `v-list-items`

That is why there is no way of avoiding the `v-list` component.

I have attached a pen to help you in better understanding how you can use a custom component inside `v-list/v-list-item` of `v-autocomplete`: https://codepen.io/abdullah-shabaz/pen/MWwZNYW

If you are having some problems with styling your `book` component please tell me. I am sure I can help you with it.

Comment: it is very good `codepen` example .espacely for see how implement vuetify on vue from scratch :) I end up implent my own `menu` `activator` by  `v-text-field` I can will put the answer here. but is not exacly explain way ther is the comment "Only needed when providing your own v-list-item" mean that there is a way to put my own `v-list-item`

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, I was looking for the same thing so if anybody needs this in the future, the answer is:

```html
<template v-slot:item="{item, on, attrs}">
    <v-list-item
        v-bind="attrs"
        v-on="on"
    >
        <v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-icon v-if="attrs.inputValue">mdi-checkbox-marked</v-icon>
            <v-icon v-else>mdi-checkbox-blank-outline</v-icon>
        </v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>{{ item.text }}</v-list-item-title>
        </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
</template>
```